# Receiving null error code on javascript on site

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a sticky menu. My code works great in jsfiddle, but when I take it over to my site it doesn't work. In my console, I see the error:

Typeerror: fixheader is null

This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var fixheader = document.getElementById("fixheader");
var sticky = fixheader.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    fixheader.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    fixheader.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
        <div id="fixheader">
            <div class="inner">
                <div id="ToggleMenu" class="fa fa-bars normal"></div>
                <div class="header-logo">
                    <a href="https://www.myurl.com/"><img src="https://cdn10.bigcommerce.com/s-fctqc2/product_images/logo_website_1464304863__33790.png" id="LogoImage" alt="http://www.myurl.com/" border="0"></a>

                </div>
                <div class="header-secondary">
                    <ul class="pages-menu sf-menu sf-horizontal sf-js-enabled">
        <li class="HasSubMenu">
        <a href="http://www.myurl.com/meet-them/" class="sf-with-ul"><span>zip</span><span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
    <li><a href="https://www.myurl.com/meet-them/">Meet Them!</a></li><li><a href="http://www.myurl.com/free-patterns-them/">Patterns</a></li><li><a href="https://www.myurl.com/videos/">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
    </li>   <li class="HasSubMenu">
        <a href="http://www.myurl.com/wood-looms/" class="sf-with-ul"><span>Shop</span><span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
    <li><a href="/wood-looms/">Wood Looms</a></li><li><a href="/plastic-looms/">Plastic Looms</a></li><li><a href="/sock-looms/">Sock Looms</a></li><li><a href="/zip-looms/">zip Looms</a></li><li><a href="/kits/">Loom Kits / Bundles</a></li><li><a href="/accessories">Accessories</a></li><li><a href="/books/">Books</a></li><li><a href="/yarn">Yarn</a></li><li><a href="http://www.myurl.com/giftcertificates.php">Gift Certificates</a></li>
</ul>
    </li>   <li class="HasSubMenu">
        <a href="/free-downloadable-patterns/" class="sf-with-ul"><span>Free Patterns</span><span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
    <li><a href="https://www.myurl.com/meet-our-designers/">Meet Our Designers</a></li>
</ul>
    </li>   <li class="HasSubMenu">
        <a href="https://www.myurl.com/learn/" class="sf-with-ul"><span>Learn</span><span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
    <li><a href="/videos">Videos</a></li><li><a href="https://www.myurl.com/loom-knitting-how-tos/">Loom Knitting How To's</a></li><li><a href="https://www.myurl.com/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
    </li>   <li class="">
        <a href="http://blog.myurl.com"><span> BLOG</span></a>

    </li>   <li class="">
        <a href="https://www.myurl.com/faqs/"><span>FAQs</span></a>

    </li>
    <!-- <li class="ic-top-search-green"><a id="search-li" title="Search" onclick="kb_showSearch()" style="display:block;width:100%">&nbsp;</a></li> -->

    <div id="SearchForm" class="cf search-dialog" title="Search" style="">
        <form action="https://www.myurl.com/search.php" method="get" onsubmit="return check_small_search_form()">
            <label for="search_query">Search</label>
            <input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" class="Textbox autobox default" value="Search">
            <input type="submit" class="Button" value="" name="Search" title="Search">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var QuickSearchAlignment = 'right';
        var QuickSearchWidth = '390px';
        lang.EmptySmallSearch = "You forgot to enter some search keywords.";
        // uniform() is deprecated in Blueprint theme; remove binding below when removing uniform
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            $('input[type=checkbox], select').not('.UniApplied').uniform();
        });
    </script>
</ul>
                </div>
                <div id="cart-amount">
                    <a href="https://www.myurl.com/cart.php" class="Cart"><span class="bag-handle"></span><span class="total"></span></a>
                </div><!-- end cart-amount -->
            </div><!-- end inner -->
        </div><!-- end Header -->
    </div><!-- end inner -->
</div>
```

My jsfiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/xw8atLgq/

How do I fix this? I searched for similar problems in Stack Overflow but none seems to relate quite to my coding. Thanks in advance.
Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks all! Managed to fix it. It was a combination of 2 things; 1) the javascript needed to be moved down since it was being called too early and 2) I had a CSS style in there that was overriding the static position, so it wouldn't show. All resolved!

Comment: Please paste the relevant part of the HTML here as well. Other than that, I don't see any problem with your code

Comment: JSFiddle runs code inside a load event handler by default

Comment: Is it possible to adapt my code to do the same? If so, how?

Comment: Either putting a function call to <body onload="init_on_load()"> or window.onload=init_on_load; per JQuery $(document).ready().

Answer (score -1):

You're getting a type error, meaning the element is either not on the page (make sure its id really is *fixheader*), or the script element sits above the element and the code is executed before it is loaded.

Comment: Thanks! The code is definitely there. I tried moving into the footer too, and while it no longer shows the error message, it doesn't work at all. It's almost as though it becomes redundant.

Comment: I really wanna know why this was downvoted...

Comment: I don't know. It wasn't me. Looks like someone went in and down-voted everything.